# Mailgun call to send message to multiple recipients is not returning to caller - example provided

Tags: php, mailgun

We are attempting to send an email to multiple recipients using the Mailgun PHP API.
We are running MG PHP lib version 2.8.1.

Our code does the following:
note: email address and domain changed for privacy reasons

```
    log_debugger('g1', 'g1');
    $params = array(
        'from'    => $msg_org . " <" . EMAIL_SENDER . ">",
        'to'      => array('joe@gmail.com'),
        'subject' => 'Hey %recipient.first%',
        'text'    => 'If you wish to unsubscribe, click http://example.com/unsubscribe/%recipient.id%',
        'recipient-variables' => '{"joe@gmail.com": {"first":"Joe", "id":1}}'
    );
    
    log_debugger('g1', 'g2');
    # Make the call to the client.
    $mgresult = $mgClient->messages()->send(MAILGUN_DOMAIN, $params);
    
    log_debugger('g1', 'g3');       
    // if the email was accepted by Mailgun then indicate the member message was delivered
    if ($mgresult->http_response_code >= 200 && $mgresult->http_response_code < 300) {
        log_debugger('mgr', $mgresult->http_response_code);     
    // else the email was not accepted by mailgun so indicate the member message failed to be delivered
    } else { 
        log_debugger('g1', 'g4');   
    }
```

The call is successfully getting to MG, but we are not getting any return from MG.  We have been sending to MG successfully for sometime and now we are attempting to send to multiple email addresses at one time.  Below is the data we are passing in as recorded by our debug log.

```
2020-08-14 12:47:01 g1
2020-08-14 12:47:01 g1

2020-08-14 12:47:01 g1
2020-08-14 12:47:01 g2
```

Here is the MG documentation - Notice the error: messages()-send should be messages()->send

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Mailgun\Mailgun;

// Instantiate the client.
$mgClient = Mailgun::create('PRIVATE_API_KEY', 'https://API_HOSTNAME');
$domain = "YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME";
$params =  array(
    'from'    => 'Excited User <YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>',
    'to'      => array('bob@example.com, alice@example.com'),
    'subject' => 'Hey %recipient.first%',
    'text'    => 'If you wish to unsubscribe, click http://example.com/unsubscribe/%recipient.id%',
    'recipient-variables' => '{"bob@example.com": {"first":"Bob", "id":1},
                               "alice@example.com": {"first":"Alice", "id": 2}}'
);

// Make the call to the client.
$result = $mgClient->messages()-send($domain, $params);
```

Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.  Logged a ticket with MG, but no reply as of yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method documented by MG for sending message is not quite correct.  I had to change the call from:

```
$mgresult = $mailgun_client->messages()->send(MAILGUN_DOMAIN, array(
```

to:

```
$mgresult = $mailgun_client->sendMessage(MAILGUN_DOMAIN, array(
```